# iterating through variables within an object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oop

OK, this might be a very silly question, but...

I have an object `x`, which contains a number of pandas dataframes (`df1`,`df2`,`df3` for sake of argument)

When the program has finished running, I want to export each of these dataframes to its own csv file. At the moment, I have a function within `x` that looks like this:

```
def export(self, path):
    self.df1.to_csv(path+"_df1.csv")
    self.df2.to_csv(path+"_df2.csv")
    self.df3.to_csv(path+"_df3.csv")
```

It works (I can just use `x.export(somepath)`, but I keep having to change it because the data I want to keep in the object changes. Can anybody tell me if there is a way of simply iterating over all of the variables within an object (they are all the same format) and (in this case) dumping them all to their respective .csv files?

Thanks

Comment: Have an instance variable `dataframes`, which is a list holding the dataframes?

Comment: wouldn't I then have to manually add all of the different variables to this list? - that's what I'm trying to avoid. I've only used three in the example, but there are a lot more in the original code!

Comment: At one point you will have to specify which dataframes you want to export. Might as well keep them in a list. I have a sense that your are trying to do something weird and your question is lacking information.

Comment: Then you should add more detail. Do the names follow a pattern, do you create them manually or with some process...?

Comment: why don't you go through all the instance variables and check if its of dataframe type and do what you want on that

Comment: Again, why don't you create that list in `__init__`. At one point you will have to specify which dataframes your object holds ANYWAY, so why not put them into a list from the beginning? (You could also write methods to add or discard from the object wrapping the list)

Comment: so @timgeb I'm a bit confused... I understand (I think) the idea that I should have a list of these variables when I `__init__` but how would that stop me having to type them all out twice? That's all I'm really looking for, so sorry if I've been unclear or it's a daft question.

Comment: @Will I still don't understand why you think you would have to type them out twice.

Comment: @timgeb Perhaps I'm being stupid, but I assumed you have to define the variables self.df1 = pd.DataFrame() self.df2 = ... etc. and then define a list containing each variable [self.df1, self.df2, etc. Have I got this wrong? Or is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: @Will how do you set the attributes `df1`, `df2` on an instance of your class right now?

Comment: @timgeb, The object is a wrapper for a  lot of similar dataframes.
When I set up the instance I initialise them within `def __init__(self):` so a series of statements like `self.df1 = pd.DataFrame() ` I then have a couple of functions within the object which summarise and export the data. I set the specific data as `instance.df1 = someDataFrame` within the main script

Comment: @Will Then you could do `self.dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame(), ...]` in `__init__` and instead of accessing `instance.df1` you would use `instance.dataframes[0]`. (Of course, you could also `pop` and `append` from that list.)

Comment: Thanks @timgeb, I do appreciate you taking the time to explain. I was wondering if this would work as a dict? I'm guessing that I could then keep the halfway sensible naming convention, while maintaining the list functionality?

Comment: @Will of course a dict will work. Don't be afraid to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `__dict__` to retrieve the attribute names and data frame objects.  You can check the object types to avoid calling `.to_csv` on something that is not a data frame.

Here is some example code that prototypes the solution.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
        self.y = pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8]])

    def export(self, path):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
            if isintance(v, pd.DataFrame):
                v.to_csv('{}_{}.csv'.format(path, k)

a = A()
a.export('dataframes')
```

Comment: I downvoted because this is - in my opinion - horrible and inefficient Python. Keep an iterable holding the dataframes. Create it in `__init__`.

Comment: @timgeb It doesn't matter if it's inefficient, the difference is less than milliseconds.

Comment: @timgeb, do give us an efficient method

Comment: @timgeb, cool, agreed with having a list of all the dataframes.

Comment: @cal97g First of all, you don't know how large the `__dict__` of OP's objects can get, so your estimated time is pure speculation. Second, readability and the principles of duck typing are violated. We can avoid explicit instance checks here and make the code faster at the same time without any cost - so we should do it.

Comment: We don't need to check the instance types, the OP said all attributes are dataframes. Say the OP needs to perform some action on one of the dataframes, a list is much less convenient than an attribute.

Comment: @timgeb I agree with you.  Instantiating the object using an iterable to hold the dataframe references is the most lightweight solution.  However, I was trying to address the original question as posed by the author.

Comment: IMO type consistency of all object attributes is an implementation detail you should never write your code around. You can't extend it reasonably.

Comment: @James I see. I would give you an upvote if you mentioned how OP can solve his problem in a better way. At the moment, you are answering an XY problem in my opinion. (edit: I'll check back later)

Comment: @James, thanks I appreciate you taking the time to answer this, but I'm getting a bit confused. There seem to be a lot of people who think I've misunderstood something important. Have I missed something obvious? I was trying to get round typing out all my instance variables twice, but wouldn't I have to do that if I put them in a list as well?